# Are apps built only for existing customers not required to use IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, appstore-approval

I’ve created an app using Ionic and Cordova.  It runs on iOS, Android, and the web.  The app helps streamline most tasks that small business owners face.  It’s basically a CRM.  In order to use the app a monthly subscription is required after 30 days.  I’ve integrated Stripe as my payment processor and works well on every platform.  However my app has been rejected twice now by Apple for not using their in-app purchaser which is required according to guideline 3.1.1.   I just submitted the app a third time and this time I’ve structured my app exactly the same way as apps such as Salesforce and Insightly.   When you download the app all you see is a login page.  There is no option to create an account or a link/information pointing the user to a website where they can subscribe.  All payment processing is handled outside of the app in the web browser.  Im really hoping this change does the trick because I want the mobile versions of my app to act as simply companion apps after they subscribe on my website.  I want to see if others could shed some light on this for me.  I believe setting it up this way allows your app to fall under guideline 3.1.3(b).  If I get rejected again for not using in-app purchases when my app is structured the exact same way as others currently on the App Store what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple:

> 3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services: Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or
>   features they have acquired elsewhere, including consumable items in
>   multi-platform games, provided those items are also available as
>   in-app purchases within the app. You must not directly or indirectly
>   target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app
>   purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing
>   methods must not discourage use of in-app purchase.

I think the important point here is you CANNOT advertise anywhere in an app that you are selling something outside of iOS. So your example of Salesforce displaying nothing but a login screen does not violate these terms. Including even a link to your homepage will get you rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

The key point that Apple generally looks for is whether or not the purchase is being made to unlock in-app functionality. If users are paying for goods or services outside of the app, then Apple doesn't make you use their in-app purchases. (see 3.1.5 (a)).

Evaluate your application to see if it is clear that users are paying for out-of-app or multi-platform functionality.

Comment: So if the app only provides a login page and nothing else isn’t it assumed that in order to use the services of this app you have to purchase them outside of the app?

Comment: I can’t find a clear answer describing specifically why companies like Salesforce and Insightly can do it this way without using the IAP, anywhere.